# NSOpenPanel is not able to add accessoryView in El Capitan(10.11)

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-elcapitan, nsopenpanel

I have noticed a strange problem in El Capitan(10.11) - I am not able to add an accessoryView to NSOpenPanel.

It was OK for Mavericks(10.9) and Yosemite(10.10). Is there anything changed in 10.11?

Here is simple code:

```
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.delegate = self
        openPanel.title = "Choose a vbo file"
        openPanel.showsResizeIndicator = true
        openPanel.showsHiddenFiles = false
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
        openPanel.canCreateDirectories = true
        openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false

        //RLFileWizardView is just custom view
        let subview = RLFileWizardView(frame: NSRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 800,height: 300))
        openPanel.accessoryView = subview
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A new property has been added to NSOpenPanel:

/* Gets and sets the disclosure state of an accessory view in an NSOpenPanel.
   If hiding / disclosing an accessory view is not applicable this property will
   behave like a read only property.
*/

> @property (getter=isAccessoryViewDisclosed) BOOL
>   accessoryViewDisclosed;

If set accessoryViewDisclosed to true, it shows accessory view again.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this and it seems to work. I need to support pre 10.11 so I ask the panel if it responds to the selector...

```
if ([panel respondsToSelector:@selector(isAccessoryViewDisclosed)]) {
    // show accessory view when dialog opens        
    panel.accessoryViewDisclosed = YES;
}
```